# 2.8 Weight painting mirror issue

Tags: weight-painting, sculpting, mirror

I've rigged a model and applied automatic weights. I went into weight painting mode to touch up and refine the bendy parts, I selected the left thigh bone and applied mirror with topographical mirror.

[image: I swipe here to showcase for the second picture highlighting my issue.]

This streak across the auto-weighted area stays in the same spot when I select the right thigh as shown here:

[image: Streak stays behind and does not seem to be affected by mirroring.]

It seems like mirroring does not work, it pastes changes from one side to the other after the options become enabled. I've been fiddling a little bit with the options to find out how to edit the pre-existing weights and have the operations applied for the bone's siblings as well. I also note that when topographical mirror is not enabled, the changes are not even applied in any form to the other bone. I appreciate any help and information to help with this problem, or if I'm misconstruing some options and coming to bad conclusions.

Comment: I tried the same thing and had the same problem.  I will mention that this is supposed to work.  side note: are your bones named correctly?

Comment: I believe so, unless blender is case sensitive. The name of the bone mapped to the vertex area I was painting on is named thigh.l and it's sibling bone was thigh.r .

Comment: That should probably work, but if you want you can try renaming those two bones to thigh.L and thigh.R, but I don't think it will make a difference.   This is annoying, because this is supposed to work, but doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I believe there is a way to mirror the weights after you have already made the adjustments on one side, but I'm not sure where that option is found.